# Choose route by domain name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 domain names pointed at an MVC application hosted by IIS7.  I need them to be separate (which is why I do not have 1 forwarded to the other). So basically if you type www.1.com or www.2.com you will get to the same MVC application but the URL will be different. Following me so far?

What I would like to do is call different controllers/routes based on the URL.  Is this something I can configure in Global.asax? If so, how?

Something like...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "www.1.com", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "www.2.com", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Instead I would have UrlRewrite in IIS rewrite your URLs like so: `http://www.2.com/2/{controller}...etc` where the 2 after the domain is the `{HTTP_HOST}` parameter being rewritten. You could then make that part of your route in MVC.

Comment: Seems like a good solution.  Any risk corrupting my existing IIS settings by installing and using the ext?

Comment: No, if it causes problems it's very simple to disable / uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Domain route option, simply try this....

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
   "{customer}.example.com", // Domain with parameters 
   "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters 
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter 
   defaults 
))
```

Answer (score -1):

What I understood is that, you are trying to build multi tenant application with ASP.NET. To achieve this you simply require to tweak IIS host header as follow.

1. Configure website in IIS which points to published version of your application.
2. Now you can edit "Binding Information" for this website and can add as many domain binding for this website. i.e. www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com
3. Last steps configure A or CNAME records for each domains to point to this IIS server IP.

Taking this further if it is require to load settings/theme/module based on requested domain name you can read this my detailed blog here http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/04/aspnet-iis-dns-records-sub-domain-on.html